# Filling not working when function in SetDelay

Tags: plotting, filling

I want to use Plot with a SetDelay. Then Filling does not work. In the following, the first works, the second does not. I would like to get the second to work:

```
Plot[{x, 2 x}, {x, 0, 5}, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, LightBlue}}]

test[x_] := {x, 2 x}
Plot[test[x], {x, 0, 5}, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, LightBlue}}]
```

Comment: Add Evauated option: Plot[test[x], {x, 0, 5}, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, LightBlue}}, 
 Evaluated -> True]

Comment: Great! Thank a lot, this works. I have to look into Evaluated. -- If you post is as an answer, I can rate it.

Comment: @Öskå you might be right, but I couldn't find it in the help menu. I also checked whether I could find something here. If a command is missing, it is hard to find what is missing. I'm glad I got an answer.